# HTML 'for' tag not working for <p> but works on <label>

Tags: html

The page I am working on has a `<label>` that has a `for=""` tag which ties an `<input type="text">`. Now, I need to change all `<label>` with `<p>`; however, the `for=""` don't work on `<p>` tags. Therefore, What can provide the same functionality as in "for" for `<p>` elements?

I can't use id's because it breaks the .js functions :-(

Comment: This seems to be a classic XY Problem. We'll have a better answer if you explain *why*  you need to replace all `<label>` with `<p>`. Can you speak to that a bit?

Comment: Instead of changing `<label>` to `<p>` why not just use CSS to make the `<label>` _act_ like a `<p>` tag?

Answer (score 3):

A `<label>` labels a form control. The `for` attribute is one way to associate a `<label>` with a form control.

A `<p>` is a paragraph. It is not a label. It does not label a form control. There is no `for` attribute for `<p>` elements because it makes no sense for there to be one.

`<label>` and `<p>` elements are **not** interchangeable. You need to reevaluate your supposed need to replace one with the other.

Comment: Quentin - Thank you so much. You opened my eyes. :-)